# SQL subquery ORA-01427

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

My sql code:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM T_DATA_ALUNO_TURNO at, T_DATA_TURNO dt
WHERE at.ALUNOID = (SELECT DISTINCT ALUNOID
                    FROM T_DATA_ALUNO_REGLECTIVO) AND
      at.TURNOID=dt.ID;
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

Any way to do this query?

Comment: Is there anything confusing about the error message? What are you trying to do? It's not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try IN instead of = for at.ALUNOID

Comment: You don't actually know that this is the correct answer unfortunately... the OP hasn't stated what they're actually trying to do... it might be that they actually wanted equals.